# iText PDF setting font property on form acroFields

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, pdf-generation, itext

I've written some code to populate form fields in a PDF with values from a database / array (which works wonderfully).

I need / want to be able to set the textfont property of each form field to use a specific font ( Helvetica or Helvetica Neue ideally).

The loop below shows the values being set into each named form field, but the setFieldProperty doesnt work.

```
<cfset BaseFont = objJLoader.create("com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont") />
<cfset helvNeue = BaseFont.createFont(expandPath('./files/mfm/fonts/HelveticaNeue.ttf'), BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED) />

<cfset pdfForm = pdfStamper.getAcroFields() />

<cfloop collection="#user#" item="key">
    <cfset pdfForm.setField(lcase(key),user[key]) />
    <cfset pdfForm.setFieldProperty(lcase(key), "textfont", helvNeue) />
</cfloop>
```

I get the following error when running the code:

```
The setFieldProperty method was not found.
```

I have tried using the built-in iText support in ColdFusion as well as using JavaLoader to read in the latest itextpdf-5.4.2.jar file.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or how I can resolve the issue to get the setFieldProperty to work?

Many thanks

Comment: The last time I wrote Cold Fusion code was in 1996 and I currently don't speak any dead languages anymore, but in Java, the `setFieldProperty()` method needs four parameters, and I only see three parameters in your call to that method...

Comment: Hi Bruno. I have also tried with a fourth parameter set to null or "" with the same result. BTW, ColdFusion is not dead.

Comment: I was just teasing you ;-) I don't know why CF can't find the ´setFieldProperty()´ method. It's there in the Java version. The missing parameter was the only difference I saw as far as I understand the awkward CF lingo.

Comment: I'm just wondering if it's something to do with the actual iText jar and if the PDFStamper is an interface and what it actually calls as the interface / base... this may explain why CF can see the method (or I can in the object dump) but cannot actually call it.

Comment: *Re: I don't know why CF can't find the ´setFieldProperty()´ method* The full error is [probably more like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355115/coldfusion-and-jsoup-the-addtags-method-was-not-found-error). The object methods are invoked via reflection. CF examines the argument "types" to locate a matching method signature. Given that CF is relatively typeless, there can be ambiguity. Explicitly casting the arguments to the correct type ie with `javacast` resolves the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

OK, after more digging around I have it working with the following code:

```
<cfset baseFont     = objJLoader.create("com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont") />
<cfset helvFont     = BaseFont.createFont(baseFont.HELVETICA, baseFont.CP1252, baseFont.EMBEDDED) />

<cfset pdfForm      = pdfStamper.getAcroFields() />   

<cfloop collection="#user#" item="key">

  <cfset pdfForm.setFieldProperty(lcase(key), "textfont", helvFont, JavaCast("null", " ")) />
  <cfset pdfForm.setField(lcase(key),user[key]) />

</cfloop>
```

Two things were missing:

- I was previously setting the helvFont value to a .ttf font on the server.. this didnt work. In this example I am calling the Helvetica basefont directly.
- I am making sure the null value in the setFieldProperty method is cast to a Java null.